# Why can I only declare variables in the first instance of a chain of nested closures?

Tags: javascript, closures, continuations

I'm trying to hack together a Read-Eval-Print-Loop in Javascript.  (It's for a web-based "teach yourself Javascript" platform.)  I have something that mostly works, but I'm encountering a weird bug with closures.

Here's a simplified version of the core of the loop.  I wrote it this way because I want to use closures and continuations to maintain any state created in the `eval`:

```
// listing 1

var repl = function(result) {
  return {
    result:
      result,
    then:
      function (expression, continuation) {
        return continuation(eval(expression));
      },
  };
}
```

And it almost works.  For instance, it correctly evaluates the sequence of expressions `var x = 1`, `x++`, `x`:

```
// listing 2

repl(eval('var x = 1')).then('x++', repl)
                       .then('x', repl)
                       .result

// evaluates to 2
```

So expressions can access and modify local variables that were declared earlier without polluting the global scope, which is great.  **But the variable declaration (i.e. `var ...`) only works in for the first expression in the chain.**  For instance, the sequence of expressions `var x = 1`, `var y = 2`, `y` throws a *y is not defined* error:

```
// listing 3

repl(eval('var x = 1')).then('var y = 2', repl)
                       .then('y', repl)
                       .result;

// throws "y is not defined"
```

I've found that I can avoid this error if I replace each instance of `repl` with its definition, like this:

```
//listing 4
//
// same as listing 3, but repl is replaced with its
// definition from listing 1

function (result) {
    return {
      result:
        result,
      then:
        function (expression, continuation) {
          return continuation(eval(expression));
        }
    },
  })(eval('var x = 1')).then(
    'var y = 2',
    function (result) {
      return {
        result:
          result,
        then:
          function (expression, continuation) {
            return continuation(eval(expression));
          },
      };
    }
  ).then(
    'y',
    function (result) {
      return {
        result:
          result,
        then:
          function (expression, continuation) {
            return continuation(eval(expression));
          },
      };
    }
  ).result

// evaluates to 2
```

This evaluates to 2.  So I guess I could solve my problem just by `eval`ing the definition of `repl` for each iteration.  But surely there's a better solution ... isn't there?

---

**Edit:** I experimented with replacing each instance of `repl` with `eval('('+repl+')')`, but it didn't solve the problem.  What am I missing?

Comment: The first `eval` is not happening in your REPL. It's happening in the scope of the caller, because you're calling `eval` there.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar. Does this explain the difference in behaviour between listings 3 and 4?

Comment: Hmm.  I'm still thoroughly confused.  Why is it that the subsequent evals can see the scope of the caller, and can manipulate variables in it, but they can't add to that scope?

Comment: You are cheating in the first call by evaling in the calling code rather than the repl implementation code...

Comment: I believe `eval()` operates in the scope of the function it's in. So when `repl()` calls `eval`, it modifies its own scope, but not that of other invocations of `eval`. The first one works because all the invocations of `eval` share the global scope that's being modified.

Comment: Remember, Javascript is _lexically_ scoped, not _dynamically_ scoped. So each invocation of a function has its own scope, even though it calls itself recursively.

Comment: Ah! Bingo! I'm confusing lexical and dynamic scoping. That's what I was missing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since RobG already explained the cause of the problem, I'll limit this answer to a possible workaround.

If you do not mind polluting the global scope (maybe that's even desired here?), you can use an [indirect `eval` call](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/) to force all the expressions to be evaluated globally:

```
var repl = function(result) {
  return {
    result:
      result,
    then:
      function (expression, continuation) {
        return continuation((1,eval)(expression));
      },
  };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y37Pj/

You could also call `repl` instead of continuation, so you don't need to pass it to `then` every time:

```
var repl = function(result) {
  return {
    result:
      result,
    then:
      function (expression) {
        return repl((1,eval)(expression));
      },
  };
}

repl(eval('var x = 1')).then('var y = 2')
                       .then('y')
                       .result
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y37Pj/1/

---

The solution Pitarou accepted was hidden in a jsFiddle in a comment to this answer. For reference, here's a slightly modified version of the "ugly hack" solution (which evals the source code of the function to create a closure):

```
function make_repl() {
  return {
    result: undefined,
    then: function (expression) {
      return {
        result: eval(expression),
        then: eval('('+this.then.toString()+')'),
      };
    },
  };
};

var repl = make_repl();

repl = repl.then('var x = 1').then('var y = 2').then('x + " " + y');

console.log(repl.result); // prints "1 2"

console.log(typeof(x), typeof(y));
// prints "undefined undefined", so we know the global scope was not touched
```

Comment: If I didn't mind polluting the global scope, this whole exercise would be a hell of a lot easier!

But thanks for showing me the indirect eval hack.  That one's new on me.

Comment: 'Doh!  Why didn't I think of that?  That's a real improvement. :-)

Comment: @Pitarou thanks for the suggested edit; I saw it too late, and edited the accepted solution in.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this works because the eval('('+this.then+')') is executed in the same lexical scope as the eval(expression), so the lexical scope is preserved?

Comment: @Pitarou Yes, that creates a new `then` on every `then` call, and the new function closes over the scope where `eval(expression)` took place. So variables declared in previous calls are available through the scope chain.

Answer (score 2):

Variables created by *eval* are created in the calling execution context. Therefore they are only available to other execution contexts created later on the same scope chain.

If you do:

```
eval( 'var x = 3' );
```

as global code, then a variable *x* with a value of *3* is created as a variable in the global context when the expression is evaluated. If *eval* is called from a function context, then any variable declarations are local to that context:

```
function doEval()
  eval( 'var x = 3' );
}
```

When `doEval()` is called, *x* will be created in the execution context of the function and will only be available inside the function.

E.g.:

```
function doEval() {

  // Create local variable x
  eval( 'var x = 3' );

  // x is available on this function's scope chain
  var foo = function(){alert(x)};

  foo();
}

doEval()   // shows 3

alert(x) // Refernce error, x is not defined
```

In your code, each function call creates a new execution context and variable environment that doesn't have access to the previous one. You can't get a reference to the local context or to the variable object so you can't pass it to some other function.

To evaluate multiple strings as code, you could use sequential calls to *eval* like:

```
function evaluateExpressions() {
  for (var i=0, iLen=arguments.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    eval(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

and call the function like:

```
evaluateExpressions(expr1, expr2, expr3, ...)
```

but then you might as well do:

```
eval(expr1 + expr2 + expr3 + ...)
```

or

```
eval([expr1, expr1, expr3, ...].join(';'))
```

At least calling it from inside a function means variables don't become global accidentally.

Oh, almost forgot, **eval is evil**. ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution you suggest isn't suitable for a REPL.  The whole purpose for taking this complicated approach is that I want the REPL to print a result, wait for the user to input the next line, and then execute the next line of code in the same context as the previous lines.

Comment: You could re–execute previous expressions—hold each expression in an array kept in a closure. As each `then` is executed, push the current expression onto the array and `eval` all of it. You'd need a `clear` or `reset` method that clears the expression array.

Comment: Yes, I've used a similar approach to solve other problems. The REPL runs in a WebWorker so, if it times out, the system terminates it and then initialises a new WebWorker by replaying the sequence of messages it used to create the old WebWorker.

The problem, of course is that as the history gets longer and longer it will become slow and unresponsive.  I'll also have to be very careful about how I manage side-effects each time I replay the history.  Still, it might be feasible.

Many thanks for your help.